# Save user intent before login and restore after it

Tags: php, codeigniter

Scenario: There's a public form XXX, but when it is submitted user need to be logged to continue, and after that, i need to restore the form XXX submission flow.

It's like an "continue action after login" with context.

PS: The form method is POST.

Something like:

[image: Example]

Comment: You mean user goes to `/somecontroller/protectedfunction` and because they aren't logged in they get redirected to `/login` and after they login you want them to go back to `/somecontroller/protectedfunction`? If not you really should revise your question for clarity, what does: "that i need to continue the form submission method" mean?

Comment: Whatever the case may be, you can just use sessions.

Comment: Yes, i need to go back to `/somecontroller/protectedfunction` with context from the original submission. If i use sessions i cant "simulate" a POST method submission.

Comment: you need to validate if `($this->session->sess_id) ? 'continue' : 'else' ` save all form info in new variable `temp_session` to make a login then restore form with that info and make the correct flow

Comment: Pass the data through using `$_GET`, use http_build_query  http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php, login and redirect back to the form, then on the page with the form, pull the data from the url and put it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did:

In the `verifyLogged` function:
Save current context with post/get/files and url in session.

In the `formSubmit` function:
Check if session has a previous context saved, if yes, restore variables and continue.